# Tel link tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to track clicks on tel: links globally by sending an event to Google analytics. I would do it through tag manager because that would have been easier, but the client I'm working for is a franchise and the headquarters doesn't allow Tag Manager to be used.

I've come up with this code and have tried other variations but cannot get it to work.

```
jQuery("a[href^='tel:']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        ga('send', 'event', 'Call Test', 'click', jQuery(location).attr('href'));
        phonenumber = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        window.location = phonenumber;
    });
```

It does successfully allow the call to happen but doesn't send the event to Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this and figure it out. Sharing code for others. Also, be sure to load jQuery from a CDN or internally before the code.

```
$("[href*='tel:']").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  // tel:
  if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("tel:") >= 0) {
    eventCategory = 'Call';
    eventLabel = href.replace('tel:', '');

  }   

gtag('event', 'Click', {
    'event_category': eventCategory,
    'event_label': eventLabel
  });

  ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: eventCategory,
  eventAction: 'Click',
  eventLabel: eventLabel
  });

  setTimeout(function() {

window.location = href;
  }, 500);

});
```